# The Supply Lapsed

Tags: word-usage

It seems to be standard English to write:

> Funding for the program ***lapsed***.

Based on that, could I write this:

> The supply of apples ***lapsed***.

as standard English?

Answer (score 1):

You can, but it's not as clear as the first example. "Funding" and "supply of apples" are two very different things. When you say the funding has lapsed, it's clear you mean that the funding has come to an end. [[1]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/lapse)

However, with a "supply of apples" the reader/listener is left unclear on which meaning of "lapse" you are using. Has the supply lapsed because the apples are slowly dying or have they just stopped sending for other reasons? "Lapsed" here does not clarify your meaning, as a supply of apples has many possible risks.

If you said "The supply of apples lapsed on account of..." or "...due to..." then it would be a lot more clear. The same could be said for the first example, but it can easily be omitted because funding only has one risk: ending.

Comment: I dunno... *lapsed* doesn't have all that many meanings. The reason the apples example doesn't make sense is because although it kinda-sorta sounds like it, *lapsed* doesn't actually mean "stopped". See J.R.'s answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say no.

The verb *lapse* refers to an expiration of sorts. From NOAD:

> **lapse** (*v.*) become invalid because it is not used, claimed, or renewed; expire : *my membership to the gym has lapsed*.

In the case of lapsed funding, that doesn't normally refer to running out of money, but running out of an allotted time.

For example, a town might decide to fund its community parks with a two-year levy. When the funding has lapsed, the levy has expired, meaning it must be renewed or the parks department will no longer receive funding.

Apple supplies *run out* or *diminish* – they don't *lapse*.